# How to find reason of rising count of NGINX open descriptors?

Tags: linux, nginx, file-descriptors

From time to time on the production server rise count of NGINX open descriptors. After that queue of connections is filled up. Also CPU usage rise to the max.

This stops automatically after 1 minute. On NGINX Amplify it looks like this:

[image: nginx open descriptors graph]

I'm not have any idea. Where to dig?

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found on graph of HTTP Errors (same screenshot)
Mass of HTTP 5XX errors is cause of opens many file descriptors. It opens to write error log.

Finding the reason of errors is going out of original question.
But in error log I only see mass of `connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream` messages.
By some reason all fpm workers waiting for something aproximately 40-60 seconds. I guess it is something in the php app, most likely database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm still investigating of reason for this. I will update answer when found origin for this errors.